# WP_Query to find any posts with either a post_modified or post_date within the selected date range

Tags: wordpress

We have a REST endpoint within Wordpress that lists posts that were modified between two dates.  I'm trying to modify this to include any posts that were either published or modified within the selected dates, but I'm having trouble with that query.  The relevant portion of the query is shown below:

```
// If a date has been specified, ensure the date query is performed by last modified date.
if ( $start_date || $end_date ) {
    $query_args['date_query'] = array(
        'column' => 'post_modified',
    );
}

if ( $start_date ) {
    $query_args['date_query'][] = array(
        'after' => $start_date . ' 00:00:00',
    );
}

if ( $end_date ) {
    $query_args['date_query'][] = array(
        'before' => $end_date . ' 23:59:59',
    );
}

$query = new \WP_Query( $query_args );
```

When I try changing this (per the suggestion in this post https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/215552/posts-modified-in-the-last-48-hours) to the following, I'm getting more articles than I should - and I think the OR relation might be the problem.

```
// If a date has been specified, ensure the date query is performed by last modified date.
if ( $start_date || $end_date ) {
    $query_args['date_query'] = 
        array(
            'relation'   => 'OR',
        array(
            'column' => 'post_modified',
        ),
        array(
            'column' => 'post_date',
        )
    );
}

if ( $start_date ) {
    $query_args['date_query'][] = array(
        'after' => $start_date . ' 00:00:00',
    );
}

if ( $end_date ) {
    $query_args['date_query'][] = array(
        'before' => $end_date . ' 23:59:59',
    );
}
```

There are other portions to this query that also check if certain taxonomy exists or not.  I'm wondering if the OR relation is causing the query to show all articles that are only matching one of the conditions.  Please let me know if you have any suggestions on how I can find any articles that have either a post_modified or post_date that falls within the specified date range - and that will work when there are additional required conditions such as the taxonomy portion of the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this working with the following code:

```
if ( $start_date && $end_date ){

    $query_args['date_query'] = 
    array(
        'relation'   => 'OR',
    array(
        array('column' => 'post_date',
        'after' => $start_date . ' 00:00:00',
        'before' => $end_date . ' 23:59:59',
    ),
    array('column' => 'post_modified',
        'after' => $start_date . ' 00:00:00',
        'before' => $end_date . ' 23:59:59',
    )
    )
    );

}
```

The problem I experienced was that I wasn't putting the start/end dates within each array section separately.  Hope this helps someone!